# Arch - No output from my usb-c to hdmi hub

Tags: arch-linux, hdmi

I'm trying to connect my pen display to my laptop through a usb hub with a '4k hdmi' port, but neither the tablet nor the other monitor I've tried have gotten any signal. It's possible that the port is just dead, but I'd like to know if there's a package I'm missing before I look for a new one.

Specifically, I have a usb-c going from my laptop to the 'host' port, which enables all the other connections, and I have a second one going to the 'power in' port, which doesn't seem to effect anything whether it's in or not. Then I have the hdmi on the hub filled by my tablet cable, which is a male hdmi at the base, branching into a usb-c that connects to the screen, a male usb that handles pen input, and a female usb that powers the screen, both usb cables work, the screen turns on, no signal is found.

Apologies in advance for the wall of text, I wanted to be precise.

Answer (score 0):

Very very vague answer:

> "usb hub with a '4k hdmi' port"

That *usually* works by having [some](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB-C#Alternate_Mode_partner_specifications) of the 4 USB-C lanes switch to [alternate mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB-C#Alternate_Mode_partner_specifications), which are then passed on to the HDMI port.

That in turn require's your computer's USB-C to be able to support alternate mode for HDMI, and it also must be connected to the graphics card of your laptop.

And that in turn requires the correct Linux drivers, both for the USB-C port and the graphics card, and that may or may not work with your laptop, because laptops are notorious for implementing their own hardware solutions which work only with the supplied Windows drivers, and not with generic Linux drivers.

So to find out, google for alternate USB-C mode support under Linux, google for what degree and how that is supported under Arch, then check your logs and see if you have it working on your laptop.

So there's quite a bit of complexity to that whole thing.